# Detecting mouse move in a transparent image

Tags: c#, image, transparent

I have an image on my form which is a PNG of a car, and the background is transparent.  In C# I am using e.Graphics.DrawImage to draw to the screen, but I want to be able to check when the mouse is moved over the image, but NOT the transparent part of the image.

Update: I had been previously drawing rectangles around the image and checking if mouse was inside the rectangle or not, but that was for the whole image not the non-transparent part of the image.

What would be the best way of going about this,

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: I would suggest using a win32 region. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-hit-testing-with-a-region-use

Comment: Thanks Neil.  I had been previously drawing rectangle around the image and then checking the rectangle if the mouse was inside.  But, I will give that Win32 region a go.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now!

I drew a rectangle around the image, and on the mouse move event, I retrieved the current pixel from the cursor location, and then got the Alpha channel from the colour.  Then just checked for when the Alpha channel was not equal to 0.